# How to use UTF8 in the Metropolis theme?

Tags: beamer, symbols, unicode, presentations

I want to make a presentation with Metropolis in the SharedLatex but I want to use utf8 so I can use the symbols from the PT-BR language. But when I try `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` it changes the theme.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! This seems completely unrelated. As far as I remember Metropolis uses XeLaTeX and that's a unicode-aware engine, so there's no need for inputenc. Could you please post a compilable code example that shows the problem (MWE)?

Answer (score 2):

Run this with `xelatex` or `lualatex`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usepackage[portuguese, brazilian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{test}
A língua portuguesa (português) é uma língua do ramo romanês da família do idioma 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```